# Angular JS environment configuration without IDE

Tags: javascript, java, angular

I am totally new to Angular JS, And I have been given an application developed in Angular JS, I am supposed to run that application on server without any IDE.

How can I do that? I tried to research online but most of the tutorials are recommending using IDE.

I tried to run it from console using following command

```
 ng serve --open
```

but getting following error

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Do I need to install any library? how to do that?

**Note:** I don't know if it is relevant but back-end of this application is written in Java (I am the developer).

Comment: `ng` is the CLI for Angular, not AngularJS: https://angular.io/cli. It doesn't require an IDE, not sure what you're asking there. Also the `serve` command is for development, not production, serving.

Comment: You can follow the Angular setup [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) to start. Then [create your first app](https://angular.io/start)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to Angular, follow the steps.

- Assuming that you have NodeJS installed, go to the command prompt and type

  `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- Go to your angular project (if you have downloaded) in command prompt and type 
  `npm install`
- Finally type the following command 
  `ng server`

Also see below the links for the difference between AngularJS and Angular
https://www.simplilearn.com/angularjs-vs-angular-2-vs-angular-4-differences-article
https://gorrion.io/blog/angularjs-vs-angular